# Why can't this PHP code be exploited?

Tags: php, wordpress

Community,

I am reviewing a WordPress theme for vulnerabilities and I believe I have stumbled upon one, but for some reason it is not executing the entire script or something.

Here is the code:

```
<span style="display: none;" id="hooks"><?php echo json_encode(of_get_header_classes_array()); ?></span>
<input type="hidden" id="reset" value="<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['reset'])) echo $_REQUEST['reset']; ?>" />
```

But for some reason, the script stops executing and only prints some of the code, here is what the source looks like:

```
<span style="display: none;" id="hooks">
```

And it never closes the span tag.  I was wondering why this is happening.

This is the function:

```
function of_get_header_classes_array() 
{

global $of_options;

foreach ($of_options as $value) 
{
    if ($value['type'] == 'heading')
        $hooks[] = str_replace(' ','',strtolower($value['name']));  
}

return $hooks;
}
```

Anyone know why I can't perform XSS is I inject code into $_REQUEST['reset'] ?

Comment: Have you tried to `print_r($_REQUEST)` right before the `if(isset(...))`?  It's possible some logic before that "unset" it.

Comment: try `var_dump( $of_options )` inside your function to see its content

Comment: Are you examining the DOM in an inspector or viewing the raw source? Many DOM inspectors will clean up html which might explain why it isn't appearing. Just a guess.

Comment: It can also always be that you are injecting thecode wrongly somehow and thus stop the function from working ..

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are hitting an error inside of of_get_header_classes_array. Check your error log and make sure error_reporting is turned on?

As for is this exploitable, there might be validation on the reset param earlier in the code. If there is absolutely no validation you can go to town on it.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by error_reporting, can you please elaborate?  And yes, the reset variable is definitely not safe.

Comment: I added 

error_reporting(E_ALL);

to both pages, will it output errors to the page it is called on?

Comment: It should go to your error log. You can set http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors to make it actually display on the screen. You can also setup a custom error handler but if all else fails you should break out a debugger but that is kinda hard to explain (there are whole guides to debugging php).